# how do I access a virtual site on a local lan?

Tags: apache2

The sites are created and are working when accessing over the Internet. I used to access a particular site by the local ip address and the site name. EX 192.168.1.2/name.com . Is name.com just the domain name?
This stopped working and I never had time to resolve for the it. BTW when I type the ip address in the browser, it returns with the first name website in the virtual website file list, sites-available directory. I've tried different variations of the name but I haven't had any luck typing a specific domain name.
Any suggestions? I am also wondering if a firewall could be blocking any local address access to the websites. I think not because the ip address of the hosting systems yields the first website (name begins with "a").
Thanks in advance for any ideas

Comment: Just to confirm, the websites are perfectly accessible using the public domain names, yes? Is the web server running Apache or something else? Will any of the sites being hosted force a redirect if accessed from an unrecognized address? 

Comment: yes, Apache, could you elaborate more on the 3rd question?

Comment: For the third question, I'm wondering if going to one of your sites with a "wrong URL" will force it to redirect you to the correct address. For example, some WordPress or Moodle systems will do this (if configured to do so) to ensure that people are always visiting a site with SSL or with a specific URL (if there are redirects). If the answer is "no" to the third question, then I can provide an answer that consists of a single Apache configuration file that will give you what you need.

Comment: no redirection is happening, please provide the config file

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like there was likely an Apache configuration file that was set up to point all bare IP requests to the `/var/www` directory. By appending the directory name of the site that you were seeking, you could load the page normally. In order to do something similar, you'll need a "bare" Apache config file to exist.

Here's how you make one:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Navigate to the Apache `sites-available` directory:

   ```
   cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
   ```
2. Create a new file that will be used internally. Perhaps you can call it something like `000-local.conf`:

   ```
   sudo vi 000-local.conf
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** Feel free to use any text editor that you are comfortable with. The example of `vi` above is more a force of habit than a direct endorsement.</sub>
3. Paste the following into your new file:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerAdmin none@noaddy.com
           DocumentRoot /var/www

           ServerName 192.168.1.2
           ServerAlias 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.*
           DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

           ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/local-error.log
           CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/local-access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>

   <Directory /var/www>
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride All

           Order Allow,Deny
           Allow From All
   </Directory>
   ```
4. Save the file
5. Enable the config file:

   ```
   sudo a2ensite 000-local.conf
   ```
6. Restart (or reload) Apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
7. Give it a go in your browser of choice

Some things to note:

- if any other configuration file has `192.168.1.2` as its `ServerName`, then there will be a conflict. You will want to ensure that every other site has a FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name — Something like website.com) as its `ServerName` value.
- if a configuration file is configured to listen for `*` in the `ServerAlias`, then you'll want to ensure it appears *after* `000-local.conf` alphabetically in the directory.

So long as the sites contained in the directory will not force a redirection from `192.168.1.2/website.com` to `website.com`, then you should be able to access these resources locally without first performing a DNS lookup outside the network.

Answer (score -1):

From what i understand `192.168.1.2/name.com` is translated as for system path, for example this IP has host which will redirect to /home/www/ and `/name.com` will be formated to /home/www/name.com/. So if your site is not showing then probably your folder name.com does not have any file associated with Web server (html,htm,php,etc.). If you want to change IP into domain name then you must use either DNS server that will know how to translate it to IP or edit /etc/hosts with this pattern: IP domain name (for example 2.2.2.2 this.is.site), also you should assign in host config file which IP is for him, if you have not done it yet.

Comment: a website can be accessed if at an offsite location ex; test.com typed for a url, if I attempt to access the website locally ex: 192.168.10.12/test.com typed in the url, error 404, this used to work??? I think that I used the joomla directory (test.com)to pick the proper virtual website, the apache log indicates that it is being accessed but the right website isn't being returned,